# Compile error of the .f source code in gfortran; reading a text file into 2D array

Tags: fortran90

I have a problem with the following source. When it is compiled in gfortran, it does not work properly and then two error message showed up. 
How do I solve this problem?
Any comment would be very helpful. 
Thanks in advance.

```
  program driver
  integer i,ln,n,e,count,x,a,b,total
  character driverid*12,var*12,ch*12
  parameter (n=720321)
```

c      parameter (n=55062)
      dimension var(n),a(n),b(n)

```
  write(*,*) 'input run id(text)'
  read(*,55) driverid
```

55    format(a)

```
  ln=index(driverid,' ')-1
  open(6,file=driverid(1:ln)//'.out',form='formatted'
 +,status='unknown')
  open(1,file=driverid(1:ln)//'.txt',status='old')


  do i=1,2
  read(1,*)
  end do

  read(1,*) (var(i),i=1,n)

  close(1)


  total=0      
  count=1
  do i=1,n
  b(i)=0
  read(var(i),*,iostat=e) x    
  if (e .eq. 0) then
    a(count)=x
    count=count+1
  else
    ln=index(var(i),' ')-1
    if (var(i)(ln-1:ln-1) .eq. 'r') then
     var(i)=var(i)(1:ln-2)
    else
     var(i)=var(i)(1:ln-1)
    end if
    read(var(i),'(i)') b(count-1)
  end if
  end do

  do i=1,count
   total=total+1+b(i)
  end do


  do i=1,total
   write(6,'(10i)') (a(i),j=1,b(i))
  end do

  close(6)

  end
```

Error message is following as

$ gfortran driver.f
driver.f:43.23:

```
    read(var(i),'(i)') b(count-1)
                   1
```

Error: Nonnegative width required in format string at (1)
driver.f:53.20:

```
   write(6,'(10i)') (a(i),j=1,b(i))
                1
```

Error: Nonnegative width required in format string at (1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When specifying a format for an integer, you *must* specify the field width. If you want to have it flexible, you can set it to zero:

```
write(6, "(10I0)") ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your commment. Now it was compiled. Another error was occured, though. I am too ignorant of any kind of programming language. I will keep going to learn this interesting world.